# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ewm'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe (`df`) :

```
Name: BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP_EUR, dtype: float64
date
2008-02-04    125761.886753
2008-02-05    123681.237732
2008-02-06    124062.436220
2008-02-07    121107.388396
2008-02-08    124216.990692
2008-02-11    122075.831250
2008-02-12    126868.359688
2008-02-13    124942.668750
2008-02-14    124220.030625
2008-02-15    121296.275000
2008-02-18    123004.414768
2008-02-19    119431.907487
2008-02-20    113577.349414
```

of type : `datatype <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

and am trying to calculate the exponentially weighted moving average of the time-series that I wish to capture.

I am using the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'': stockData[unique_id+"_MKTCAP_EUR"]})

McapResult = df.ewm(alpha=0.1, adjust=False).mean().iloc[-1]
```

Where `McapResult` is the last value in the exponential series

but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ewm'

Could someone let me know what I need to do to fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`Series.ewm`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ewm.html) rather as create new `DataFrame` `df` - result is same:

```
import pandas as pd

stockData = pd.DataFrame({'BBG.XLON.VOD.S': {pd.Timestamp('2008-02-14 00:00:00'): 124220.030625, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-20 00:00:00'): 113577.34941400001, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-08 00:00:00'): 124216.99069200001, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-13 00:00:00'): 124942.66875, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-15 00:00:00'): 121296.27499999999, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-06 00:00:00'): 124062.43622, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-19 00:00:00'): 119431.90748699999, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-04 00:00:00'): 125761.886753, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-11 00:00:00'): 122075.83125, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-07 00:00:00'): 121107.38839600001, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-05 00:00:00'): 123681.23773199999, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-18 00:00:00'): 123004.414768, pd.Timestamp('2008-02-12 00:00:00'): 126868.35968800001}})
stockData.index.name = 'date'
```

```
print (stockData)
            BBG.XLON.VOD.S
date                      
2008-02-04   125761.886753
2008-02-05   123681.237732
2008-02-06   124062.436220
2008-02-07   121107.388396
2008-02-08   124216.990692
2008-02-11   122075.831250
2008-02-12   126868.359688
2008-02-13   124942.668750
2008-02-14   124220.030625
2008-02-15   121296.275000
2008-02-18   123004.414768
2008-02-19   119431.907487
2008-02-20   113577.349414

unique_id = 'BBG.XLON.VOD.S'
McapResult = stockData[unique_id].ewm(alpha=0.1, adjust=False).mean().iloc[-1]
print (McapResult)
122786.42433
```

EDIT:

I think error cause lower verion of pandas as `0.18.0`, because `pandas.Series.ewm` is [`New in version 0.18.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ewm.html).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code but still getting the AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ewm' problem.  not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What is your version of pandas? `print pd.show_versions()`. If bellow `0.18`, it is problem, because `pandas.Series.ewm` is  `New in version 0.18.0.` - [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ewm.html). I have last version `0.18.1` and it works very well.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm running 0.17 so I guess an upgrade is in order :).  Is there any documentation on how to do this painlessly? Thanks

Comment: What `os` use? `win`, `linux`, ...? Do you use [`Anaconda`](https://docs.continuum.io/) ?

Comment: hmmm, try `cmd` and then `conda install pandas`, then `y`.